# Is fragment shader run at out of screen?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I use webgl 1.0.

I want to know that if I set vertices out of -1 ~ 1 range, fragment shader run at out of screen(also framebuffer) or not.

[example]
If I set like below.
draw type : `gl.LINES`
vertices  : `[-100000,-100000, 100000, 100000]` <--- 1 line made by 2 point

I think display result is same when I set
vertices  : `[-1,-1, 1, 1]`
(Both result are show 1 straight line from left bottom to right top.)

I want to know first example is slower performance caused by lot of running fragment shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only the fragments which are in the view volume are processed by the fragment shader. The other fragments are clipped.

The [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) are clipped in the [Vertex post-processing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Vertex_post-processing) stage.

The [Clipping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping) rule is applied on the clip space coordinates (`gl_Position`):

```
-.w <= .x, .y, .z <= .w
```

Fragment processing is done later after the [Rasterization](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Rasterization).
See also [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)